# Error: login() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, login-page

I tried coding a login page using `tkinter`, but I'm getting an error. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def register(event):
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry("320x250")
    username =StringVar()
    password =StringVar()
    contact  =StringVar()
    email    =StringVar()
    Label(screen1,text="Please enter your details below").pack()
    Label(screen1,text="Username").pack()
    Entry(screen1,textvariable = username)
    Label(screen1,text="Contact").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=contact)
    Label(screen1, text="Email id").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=email)
    Label(screen1, text="Password").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=password)
    Button(screen1, text="Register", width=10, height=1).pack()

def login(event):
    screen2 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen2.title("Register")
    screen2.geometry("320x250")
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    Label(screen2, text="Username").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable=username)
    Label(screen2, text="Password").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable=password)
    Button(screen2, text="Login", width=10, height=1).pack()

def main_screen():
    global screen
    screen = Tk()     #creating tk window
    screen.geometry("320x250")
    screen.title= ("notes 1.0")
    Label(screen,text="").pack()
    Button(screen,text="Login",height="2", width="30",command=login).pack()
    Label(screen,text="").pack()
    Button(screen,text="Register",height="2", width="30",command=register).pack()
    screen.mainloop()
main_screen()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matrena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: register() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matrena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: login() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

Comment: Where were you expecting that `event` parameter to two of your functions to come from?  The function called via the `command=` option of a Button receives no parameters.

Comment: <event> parameter is there a need for this? Even if you fix this you will run in other problems like global/local variables... I suggest that you code the whole thing again and start with building classes that will help you in term of global/local scope.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why only some Tkinter callback functions need to have an argument but others don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15889126/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here. First off, you shouldn't pass `event` to the `register()` and `login()` functions. If you use the `.bind()` function, then you have to use event, but otherwise, that will give you an error.

Here is your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
screen = Tk()     #creating tk window
screen.geometry("320x250")
screen.title("notes 1.0")
Label(screen,text="").pack()
def login():
    screen2 = Toplevel()
    screen2.title("Register")
    screen2.geometry("320x250")
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    Label(screen2, text="Username").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable=username)
    Label(screen2, text="Password").pack()
    Entry(screen2, textvariable=password)
    Button(screen2, text="Login", width=10, height=1).pack()
def register():
    screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen1.title("Register")
    screen1.geometry("320x250")
    username =StringVar()
    password =StringVar()
    contact  =StringVar()
    email    =StringVar()
    Label(screen1,text="Please enter your details below").pack()
    Label(screen1,text="Username").pack()
    Entry(screen1,textvariable = username)
    Label(screen1,text="Contact").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=contact)
    Label(screen1, text="Email id").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=email)
    Label(screen1, text="Password").pack()
    Entry(screen1, textvariable=password)
    Button(screen1, text="Register", width=10, height=1).pack()
Button(screen,text="Login",height="2", width="30",command = login).pack()
Label(screen,text="").pack()
Button(screen,text="Register",height="2", width="30",command=register).pack()




screen.mainloop()
```

I have noticed the project isn't finished, though, so if you want me to finish it, just ping me!!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much.I saw 3 to 4 videos on creating a login page and got confused hence the unnecessary event parameter, thank you for informing me about .bind() function. Will ping you on the updates of the project :)

Comment: Can you please check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225666/how-to-define-a-class-date-day-month-year-in-python-with-functions-to-accept