# How to define a class Date (Day, Month, Year) with functions to accept a date from the user and display it?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to define a class `Date (Day, Month, Year)` with functions to accept a date from the user and display it. I also want to throw user-defined exception “invalid Date” if the input
date is invalid. I have the following working code, but I don't know how to put it in a `Date` class.

```
import datetime

inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yy' : ")
day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')

isValidDate = True
try :
    datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
except ValueError :
    isValidDate = False

if(isValidDate) :
    print ("Input date is valid!")
else :
    print ("Input date is invalid!")
```

This is what I have come up with so far but I'm not being able to use the `inputDate` value in the `put_date` function. I read somewhere that it can be done by returning the value in the first function and then using it in the other one, but that hasn't worked either.

```
import datetime

class Date:
    def __init__(day, month, year):
        isValidDate = True
        try :
            datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
            datetime.datetime(int(day), int(month), int(year))
            datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month),int(day))
        except ValueError :
            isValidDate = False

        if(isValidDate) :
            print ("Input date is Valid!")
        else :
            print ("Input date is Invalid")

    def get_date(self):
        inputDate = input("Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yy' : ")
        day,month,year = inputDate.split('/')
        date1= Date(int(day), int(month),  int(year))


    def put_date(self):
        print ("Input date: " +inputDate)


date1= Date()
date1.get_date()
date1.put_date()
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should not define your own CLASS for this.  The `datetime.datetime` class already knows how to store a date.  It's perfectly reasonable to have a FUNCTION that queries the user, validates the input, and returns a `datetime.datetime` object, but you don't have any additional state info to store, so I don't see the need for a subclass.

Comment: Input/output should not be done in a class. Separation of concern. So the answer to "How to..." is "You don't".

Comment: Also, don't use `split` and manually construct the object. Use `strptime`. More specifically, a two digit `year` is probably not what you want and leading zeros are not properly handled here

Comment: @TimRoberts: It's probably homework.

Comment: My vote is on "I need to..." meaning "My teacher created a poorly thought-out assignment to...".

Comment: You should start by defining a class: i.e. `class Date:`, and then add a `def __init__(day, month, year):` method to it. You can validate the argument in there.

Comment: I agree with you'll, it's very unnecessary to create a class here. That was my initial thought too. But like @martineau said, this is a minor assignment that I need to do, hence the word "need".

Comment: Matrena: When replying to someone, it's important to put @ their_username in it somewhere so they will be notified of your response (like I just did). I also suggest that you [edit] your question and put code in it based on my earlier suggestion.

Comment: @martineau Got it! I've added the code that I've tried out so far. Can you please check it? So the validation part comes under def __init__(day, month, year): but what about the accepting and displaying of the date?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a `def __init__(day, month, year):` anywhere in your updated question.

Comment: @martineau Sorry for that. Now how do I proceed? Is there a way where I can pass the value accepted from the user to the day, month, year attributes?

Comment: Yes, you can create an instance of the class — in the upper code — via `my_date = Date(day, month, year)`.

Comment: @martineau Something like `my_date = Date(11, 02, 2002)` ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I also wanted to mention that you can define a custom exception via something like `class DateError(Exception): pass` and then `raise DateError` when `isValidDate` is `False` in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242309/discussion-between-matrena-melgalis-and-martineau).